# Get pattern from d3 and set it like border of div

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, c3.js

I created a pattern for d3:

```
d3.select('defs')
    .append('pattern')
    .attr('id', hatchId)
    .attr('width', 14)
    .attr('height', 14)
    .attr('patternUnits', 'userSpaceOnUse')
    .attr('patternTransform', 'rotate(45 0 0 )')
    .attr('fill', color)
    .append('rect')
    .attr('height', 14)
    .attr('width', 14);
d3.select(hatchId)
     .append('line')
     .attr('y2', 14)
     .attr('opacity', '0.3')
     .style('stroke', '#fff')
     .attr('stroke-width', 6);
```

And return it like color in c3.js options:

```
data: {
            type: 'bar',
            columns: [],
            types: {},
            axes: {},
            classes: {},
            color: function (color, d) {
                .....
                return `url(#${hatchId})`;
            },
        },
```

it looks something like this

[image]

but I need to add elements with such a pattern - for example, a legend with a border

I try to create :

```
`<div style="border-color: url(#${hatchId});">Name</div>`
```

Pattern not found

Is it possible to get pattern from d3 and use it in other places except c3?

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: @ksav I replaced div with border-color on div with svg object like circle and used url(#hatchId) for it

Comment: Was my answer helpful in reaching that solution?

Comment: @ksav Yes I think :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible.

The [pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/pattern) created by d3 is just regular SVG. You can apply it as a fill or stroke to an SVG shape, but you can not apply it to HTML.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 230 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="star" viewBox="0,0,10,10" width="5%" height="5%">
      <polygon points="0,0 2,5 0,10 5,8 10,10 8,5 10,0 5,2"/>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <circle cx="50"  cy="50" r="50" fill="url(#star)"/>
  <rect x="120"  width="100" height="100" fill="none" stroke-width="6" stroke="url(#star)"/>
</svg>
```